# Redirect to specific page - .htaccess, wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

i would like to know how to redirect every url that comes after /old-articles/   to my  /blog/ page.
ex.: https://www.mywebsite.com/old-articles/some-article/ - - > https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/
I have tried many things in my .htacces file but i can not find a solution.
Apache server - wordpress site

i have already tried:
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^old-articles(.*)$ /blog$1 [R=301,NC,L]

Redirect 301 /old-articles/* /blog/

Redirect 301 /old-articles/(.*)$ /blog$1

Redirect 301 /old-articles(.*)$ /blog$1

Redirect 301 /old-articles(.*)$ /blog/

I have a lot of links that i want to redirect them to blog, like: 
/faq-category/* --> /blog/
i have tried the same things for that too. But the result is always the same, "Page not found", without redirecting to blog.

Comment: Share with us what you've already tried. Then we can avoid suggesting fixes that you've already tried.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Edited!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly similar to the standard "redirect all traffic to new domain" `.htaccess` code, which generally looks something like:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However since you just want to redirect a subdirectory you can do something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^old-articles(.*)$ /blog$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have already tried it. It doesn't redirect me to /blog/

Comment: Then you must have an issue with your .htaccess file or another issue, like is `mod_rewrite` enabled? Take a look at my personal site: http://xhynk.com/old-articles/1234. It uses the same code I gave you (note that it will 404 since I don't have content on that URI, but the rewrite does indeed work). You could also use a PHP solution if you can't get your .htaccess to work.